# Increasing file size upload in WP (already tried to edit php.ini and .htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, upload, php, filesize

I've tried editing php.ini as such:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

and

```
post_max_size = 40M
```

and editing .htaccess as such:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M</IfModule>
```

(an answer suggested on another post,) but am still unable to upload files larger than 2M.

The WP install is on a subdirectory, but the php.ini and .htaccess are on the root. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: See this 3 way solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868949/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-size-in-cpanel/23362591#23362591

Comment: The posting at the URL helped me solve the issue:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/172217/apache2-php5-file-upload-and-post-max-size

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always caused by your host capping it regardless of what settings you can change. They do not give users on many shared hosts the ability to change suPHP or .conf (or whatever) files, so you will have to ask them.

Comment: I was trying upload videos. I just uploaded them through FTP and access them through the URL. Seems to be working. They don't show up in the media library, though. C'est la vie...

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M'); in the wp-config.php file.
Might also be your hosting provider, but I assume since you have root access that it shouldn't be.

There's more ideas here that might be helpful.
http://wordpress.org/tags/upload_max_filesize