# Passing an array of multiple base64 strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

There are base64 strings in an array that I need to send via jquery's `$.post()` to a php.

```
var base64s = [........];
$.post("getbase64.php",
  {
    'base64s': base64s
  },
```

php:

```
$base64s = $_POST['base64s'];
//and used as `$base64s[$i]` inside a for loop.
```

It works only when there are max 2 base64 strings. Is there a maximum size for an array? or what might be the reason?

Comment: Check for 

`post_max_size` in  php.ini file

Comment: where is your error? on the php or in the js?

Comment: @Saty thanks. Can you describe a bit more. Is that on cPanel?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868949/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-size-in-cpanel)

Comment: @Saty thank you :) is that `upload_max_filesize` in php configuration in cPanel?

Comment: Yes `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` you can increase the size of it according to your requirment