# unable to upload a file on Server - error is Warning: POST Content-Length of 42669632 bytes exceeds

Tags: php, file-upload

am trying with below code php.ini file is

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_vars = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_input_time = 1000
```

and htaccess file is:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but still file is not uploading on server. warning is

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 42669632 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   16777216 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: What are the form and file HTML elements settings?

Comment: You server is currently limiting the file upload to 16777216  bytes and you are uploading 42669632  bytes. Even though you are setting the upload limit to a higher value in your script the server isn't recognising it, you need to investigate that.

Comment: @John.M how to investigate !! please help, am tired to solve this issue. thanks

Comment: This answer in another post should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868949/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-size-in-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's limited to 16MB = 16777216 bytes.

Was 16MB the upload limit before you changed the settings?

Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Yes for 16MB,
how to restart the server ?? am working live on server/cpanel !!